# Update Array where it exists or Insert new Array Item

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
 _id:'1',
name:'apple',
option:[{
weight:'10',
price:'40',
},
{weight:'40',
price:'200'}]
}
```

I want to add apple if its not in db, if its in db, I want to ckeck if weight 10 is available, if available I want to update the price if not I want to add new weight and price in option. How can I do it, in mongodb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) for this. This is not actually a single operation, so you want to submit multiple operations in a single request. Essentially attempt to write the update with [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) where data does exist or [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) the new data where it does not exist:

```
db.collection.bulkWrite([
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "_id": "1", "option.weight": "10" },
    "update": { 
      "$set": { "option.$.price": "30" }
    }
  }},
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "_id": "1", "option.weight": { "$ne": "10" } },
    "update": {
      "$push": { "option": { "weight": "10", "price": "30" } }
    }
  }}
])
```

The positive case is simply the value, and the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) "negates" the equality match, meaning the item does not exist. Of course the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) is used with [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) where it does

Given the data only one of the operations will actually match and apply as an update despite two operations being sent in the "batch".

If you want "upserts" for the whole document as well, then you need to add another operation to the end of that. Note that you cannot apply "upsert" as an option on either of the other statements, especially the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) because that would create a new document where the array item does not exist, not just the `_id`:

```
db.collection.bulkWrite([
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "_id": "1", "option.weight": "10" },
    "update": { 
      "$set": { "option.$.price": "30" }
    }
  }},
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "_id": "1", "option.weight": { "$ne": "10" } },
    "update": {
      "$push": { "option": { "weight": "10", "price": "30" } }
    }
  }},
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "_id": 1 },
    "update": {
      "$setOnInsert": {
        "option": [
           { "weight": "10", "price": "30" }
         ]
      }
    },
    "upsert": true
  }}
])
```

The [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) is the main help here apart from that last operation being the only marked as `"upsert"`. That combination makes sure that where the primary "document" is found then nothing actually happens, but when it's not found the new array item is added.

As a side note, I would strongly suggest storing numeric values actually as numeric rather than strings. Not only does it save on space in most cases but it's also far more useful that way.

Comment: Thanks, it works with option properly, but if the _id: 1 is not available it doesnot upsert

Comment: @naruto That's a different wrinkle not mentioned in the question, but really simply added as another operation. Added example and explanation.

Comment: the upsert method should be one step down of its current position, and then everything works as a charm, please edit it so other can find it useful, and thanks a lot for ur help.

Comment: @naruto Oops! Typo from typing to quickly. At least you caught it. Corrected.

Comment: sorry for bothering u, but I have one more question if u don't mind helping me, what if I have three attributes such as weight, size and price, price changes if weight and size differ, how can I upsert for this.

Comment: @naruto If you have a new question then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). But it really should not be difficult to work out that an additional condition is merely an additional query condition. You update the same way you query, which is by including both conditions in the filter option.

Comment: it did not work for me adding the additional query condition. I will ask a new question

Comment: @naruto Please ask a new question. That's what you do here and the reason why is 
because comments do not adequately explain what you are doing. That is what questions are for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806613/insert-array-in-mongidb-if-doenot-exist-else-update-it  this is the link to new question